# Automatic sorting in 'merge' function in R

Tags: r, dplyr, merge

When I run the following code, the output is already sorted.

```
small_data <- data.frame(
  V1 = c("IPC1", "IPC2"),
  V2 = c(1, 0)
)

big_data<- data.frame(
  V1 = c("IPC1", "IPC2","IPC1", "IPC2","IPC2", "IPC1"),
  V3 = c(runif(6,4,10))
)

merge(big_data,small_data,by='V1')
    V1       V3 V2
1 IPC1 7.593579  1
2 IPC1 6.343212  1
3 IPC1 6.548334  1
4 IPC2 9.813686  0
5 IPC2 9.116887  0
6 IPC2 4.253725  0
```

I do not want it sorted. So I used the `sort=FALSE` statement.
`merge(big_data,small_data,by='V1',sort = FALSE)`

The output is still the same. How do I get the output without being sorted?

I used `left_join` from `dplyr` package and it worked fine.

```
left_join(big_data,small_data,by='V1')
    V1       V3 V2
1 IPC1 7.593579  1
2 IPC2 9.813686  0
3 IPC1 6.343212  1
4 IPC2 9.116887  0
5 IPC2 4.253725  0
6 IPC1 6.548334  1
```

I need to know how to do it using `merge` function.

Comment: Yeah, `merge(.., sort=FALSE)` doesn't behave the same as `dplyr::left_join`. Not an answer, but when I need to use `base::merge` and preserve the original order, I add ordering columns. For instance, `small_data$rn <- seq(nrow(small_data)); big_data$rn <- seq(nrow(big_data)); out <- merge(big_data,small_data,by='V1'); out[order(out$rn.x, out$rn.y),]`. Ugly, yes.

Comment: @r2evans I saw that as a solution but I thought surely there must be way to stop this automatic sorting of the data frame. Hence I posted the question. Your suggestion works definitely.